# Using jq is there an easy way to combine json objects into an array

Tags: json, jq

I have two simple jsons that I want to combine into one. I am trying to bake this into some automation so that I will not need to manually combine the two each time. Is there a way with jq to combine file1.json with file2.json so that the output looks like desired.json?

file1.json

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  [
    "a",
    "b"
  ]
]
```

file2.json

```
[
  [
    "3"
  ],
  [
    "c"
  ]
]
```

desired.json

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ],
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
]
```

Comment: For a very similar Q, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210344/combine-two-json-arrays-in-a-single-file-using-jq

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly

```sh
jq -s '[map(.[0][]),map(.[1][])]'  file1.json file2.json
```

Implicitly

```sh
jq -s 'transpose | map(flatten)'  file*.json
```

Or as suggested by @peak

```sh
jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' file*.json
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `flatten` is a minefield, and perhaps even unnecessarily inefficient.  Much better to use `add`:  `jq -s 'transpose | map(add)'`